# Want to learn method for background subtraction of single frame image in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I would like to know if anyone can help me create a 2d array in python that acts as a background subtraction.

My idea is to create an array that uses the pixel value on the left side of the image and the pixel value at the far right of the image (same column) and uses those two values to plot a line function that creates values over the entire row length of the image. I would iterate this over all rows.

The reason why I would do this, is because most of the aberrations seen in the images come from the edges.

However my problem is finding a simpler method for executing this code. If anyone has suggestions please let me know

Also, I am questionable of my idea. If anyone has an idea for background subtraction, please let me know. (I have no plain static image to use as subtraction).

I have tried this for on row, but the process seems very inelegant.

here is an example of the code I am running:

'''

```
def rise_and_slope(b,e,img,axis):
    # y = mx+c
    c = b
    m = (e - b)/img.shape[axis]
    return(m , c)

def line(m,b,x):
    y = m*x + b
    return(y)


beggining = img[:][0]
end = img[:][-1]
lines = np.zeros(img.shape)
for i in range(img.shape[0]-1):

    m,c = rise_and_slope(beggining[i],end[i],img,1)
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        lines[i][j] = line(m,c,j)
```

'''

Comment: "My idea is to create an array that uses the pixel value on the left side of the image and the pixel value at the far right of the image (same column)" I'm not sure I understand. Wouldn't the pixels at the far left side and the far right side be in different columns? Can you provide a small example of an example input and output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have provided example code

Comment: This was thrown together quickly, but this is the idea that I am trying to describe. Please if there is another idea, I am eager to learn